# How are concurrent android Transitions supposed to be handled? Canceled?

Tags: android, android-transitions

I just wrote a simple custom Transition, that animates elevation.

However if I run the transition again via TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition during the previous one already running, **I do observe the previous animator still running**, *i.e. they both are running at the same time.* Visually its not a problem since the second transition always seems to overwrite the value set but the previous animator.

But' this for sure can break in some more complex scenario, so I'd best like to cancel the previous transition animators before starting the new.

Is there an api for that? I see there is protected cancel() but I don't see any of its usage. Also, I've looked at the stock transitions like ChangeBounds and also they don't seem to care